# Assigning a data attribute without a value to an Ember component

Tags: ember.js, zurb-foundation, ember-cli

I'm relatively new to Ember and am incorporating Foundation 5 into an ember-cli app using the [ember-cli-foundation-sass](https://github.com/artificialio/ember-cli-foundation-sass) addon.

I'm building an Ember component for Foundation's topbar element, and I need to set a `data-topbar` on the nav like so:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <!-- ... -->
</nav>
```

Is there any way to add an attribute binding with no associated value in an Ember component?

The following adds the `role` attribute but not `data-topbar`:

```
// app/components/topbar-nav.js

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'nav',
  classNames: ['top-bar'],
  attributeBindings: ['role', 'data-topbar'],
  role: 'navigation',

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().foundation();
  }
});
```

Setting an arbitrary value for `data-topbar`, like `'data-topbar': 'foo'`, will set the attribute on the nav, but that's not what I need:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="foo" role="navigation">
  <!-- ... -->
</nav>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always set the tagname to `''` and do the rest in the component template:

```
App.NavBarComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: '',
  role: 'navigation',

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.$().foundation();
  }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/nav-bar">
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar {{bind-attr role=role}}>
    NAVBAR
  </nav>
</script>
```

Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bewawa/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

If you set the value of the attribute to be an empty string, then this will give you the desired effect, i.e. a HTML attribute without a value.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'option',
  attributeBindings: ['value'],
  value: '',
});
```

Will give you:

```
<option value></option>
```